# Enclosing list in a box

Tags: lists, enumitem, box

When I try to enclose a list in a box

```
\fbox{
  \parbox{\textwidth}{  
  \begin{enumerate}[label=Step \Roman*]
    \item  item 1\\
    \item  item 2 \\
    \item  item 3 \\
    \item  item 4 \\
    \item  item 5\\
    \item item 6 \\
    \end{enumerate}
  }
}
```

I get a box where the "Step n " is half inside box and half outside.
[image]

Comment: Add as optional argument `[align=left]`.

Comment: Still the same output.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. At the moment we have to guess what packages etc you are using before we can compile your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With standard frame, you need only add `leftmargin=*` option to `enumerate` list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
\noindent\fbox{%
  \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}{
  \begin{enumerate}[label=Step \Roman*, leftmargin=*]
    \item   item 1
    \item   item 2
    \item   item 3
    \item   item 4
    \item   item 5
    \item   item 6
    \end{enumerate}
                    }%
        }
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to put frames etc round your list environment then I suggest using [tcolorbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) as this will give you much more control. For example, you can produce

[image]

using the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newlist{steps}{enumerate}{1}% create new steps environment
\setlist[steps]{%              configure the steps environment
  label=Step \Roman*,
  leftmargin=*,
  align=left
}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\tcolorboxenvironment{steps}{% wrap the steps environment in a tcolorbox
  colframe=red!75!black
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{steps}
    \item item 1
    \item item 2
    \item item 3
    \item item 4
    \item item 5
    \item item 6
  \end{steps}

\end{document}
```

A few comments about the code:

- The MWE example appears to be using the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package so, as above, I recommending using `\newlist` to define a custom `steps` environment and then `\setlist` to configure this enivorment.
- The `\tcolorboxenvironment{steps}{...}` command wraps the `steps` environment inside a very simple `tcolorbox`, which is highly customisable. I recommend reading the [tcolorbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) manual, after which you can configure this to your heart's content.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using tcolorboxes.
Without guessing the packages used I give you a minimal working example with `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white,sharp corners]
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item[Step 1]  item 1
    \item[Step 2]  item 2
    \item[Step 3]  item 3
    \end{enumerate}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Although it was not what I had in mind, but this has given me an excellent alternative choice.